# Anyone using the new XBOX One Kinect?

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know what or when to expect the new XBOX One Kinect sensor to work with ROS (Openni2?)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108951/anyone-using-the-new-xbox-one-kinect?/) by [TFinleyosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4405/tfinleyosu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2013-12-10

Post score: 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**EDIT :** Thiemo from the Institute for Artificial Intelligence at the University of Bremen has released a kinect v2 driver! Check out [this post from ROS news](http://www.ros.org/news/2014/09/microsoft-kinect-v2-driver-released.html) for more info.

The folks over at [openkinect](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page) seem to be hard at work in hacking kinect v2.  There's not much info on the [wiki page](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Kinect_2) as of this post, but some of the threads on [the forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/openkinect) are quite encouraging.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2014-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [isura](https://answers.ros.org/users/1583/isura/) on 2014-07-10**:
Any update on this?

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2014-12-12**:
Anyone managed to get the skeleton tracking with the Kinect v2 ? that would be awesome^^!

**Comment by [srik11](https://answers.ros.org/users/25636/srik11/) on 2016-01-17**:
Any update on the new kinect (kinect for xbpx one) ? Has anyone managed to get it run.?
Would highly appreciate your help regarding the same.

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2016-01-18**:
I got it working on Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo up to the point where I can see the colored point cloud in Rviz. I think you just have to follow the instructions here : https://github.com/code-iai/iai_kinect2

**Comment by [srik11](https://answers.ros.org/users/25636/srik11/) on 2016-01-18**:
Hey, I tried the same. I installed libfreenect2. But for me the issue is that I cannot even run with Protonect. So I was wondering whether my USB controller has any issue. I get no devices found when I run Protonect. Although the USB port is USB 3.0. Which USB controller are you using?

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2016-01-19**:
I also use USB3.0. Do you see the kinect listed with the lsusb command ? Did you try to run Protonect with the options gl, cl or cpu ?

**Comment by [srik11](https://answers.ros.org/users/25636/srik11/) on 2016-01-20**:
Hey!, Thanks, found the issue. libusb was not the latest version. But now Protonect runs with cpu and gl but does not run with cl. I am guessing opencl is not completely installed. I have an intel GPU, so i am not able to install beignet. for my kernel 3.16. Did you face this issue?

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2016-01-20**:
In the beginning I also had issues, I saw only black windows with no data I remember. I have a nVidia GPU. There was a rely I gave, you can have a look : http://answers.ros.org/question/209393/how-can-i-use-kinect-v2-with-ros-in-ubuntu-1404/
Did you get the kinect2_bridge working ?

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2016-01-21**:
You guys should really ask a new question so others can benefit from your answers.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The XBox One Kinect is completely different technology from the XBox 360 Kinect. It will not work with openni2. Someone is going to need to reverse engineer the new Kinect's protocol again unless Microsoft releases a linux SDK. (Not likely.)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-12-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-12-16**:
Does anybody know if someone started working on this?